# RDFa, Microdata and Microformat.

Tags: semantic-markup, microformats, microdata, rdfa

RDFa, Microformats and Microdata provide easy ways to include semantic markup. Are there any other similar technologies ?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

RDFa and microdata do not do very different things. All three formats do approximately the same thing in different ways, with RDFa and microdata being very similar.

Read Manu Sporny's Uber-comparison of the three for more details: http://manu.sporny.org/2011/uber-comparison-rdfa-md-uf/

Answer (score 1):

RDFa, Microformats and Microdata actually do very different things.

All 3 potentially provide a means to annotate fragments of HTML

RDFa is also a way to publish RDF in an HTML document since there is a formal model for parsing RDFa (unlike the latter).

In addition to the above, there is also [MathML](http://www.w3.org/Math/) and [RDFj](http://www.w3.org/wiki/JSON+RDF), the former which is restricted to XHTML resources (and HTML5 resources if I am not mistaken) and the latter, to Javascript/JSON resources or inline script.